# Arranging JLabels on JPanel when some of them need to be inside grid layout and some of them are not

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

I want to place a game board in JPanel and i'm using GridLayout 10x10
In addition i want to place additional labels on the same JPanel but not inside the grid.

When i'm adding this labels they are automatically added to the grid despite the fact that i fixed the size.

To summarize: 
How can i arrange in the same JPanel with grid layout a fixed board with labels and additional labels in the left area of the plane. 
[image]

Comment: You mean `panel` instead of `plane`, rite?

Comment: Sorry, Yes i mean JPanel

Comment: Use a [nested layout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).  Perhaps a `GridLayout` in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout` with a single column `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` in the `EAST`.  +1 for the artwork.

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1. I was about to tell the same. (Except the +1 part)

Comment: @HarryJoy  *"Except the +1 part"*  I'm a sucker for a screen-shot.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not two panels, one with a `GridBaglayout` and another one with a `BoxLayout` enclosed in a panel with `GridLayout`? :))